# Catalina 10.15.6 automatically connecting to NFSv3 shares on Ubuntu 20.04 machine

Tags: catalina, nfs

With this command from terminal I can succesfully connect to NFS share, but how to automate this?

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3,proto=tcp,resvport 192.168.x.x:/nfsshare /Users/xxx/nfsshare
```

Until now, I was able to connect to NFSv4 shares from Finder's Connect To Server option and then to drag that volume to Login Items in User section of System Preferences, but I had to downgrade Ubuntu's NFS support to v3, because v4 causes freezing of the whole NFS server machine. The same technique for automatic launch of shares is not working with NFSv3.

Already tried this: https://lowhangingfruit.dev/2019-10-21/automount-nfs-on-macos/, no luck.

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://lowhangingfruit.dev/2019-10-21/automount-nfs-on-macos/ is working:

I just had to remove some parameters from command and it worked out, I only left -fstype=nfs,nfsvers=3, and that's it.

Comment: In your question, you posed the same link and said "no luck" then in your answer you say "it's working."  It's helpful if you post the *complete* answer/command for future readers to see what *exactly* worked.